# Origin of "nuke Mars now"

Tags: books, the-council-wars

I'm currently reading *Emerald Sea* by John Ringo (book 2 of his *Council Wars* series). It's set several centuries into the future.
This phrase has been used, and I'm wondering if anyone knows the origin.

Extract from the book:

> "I don't buy it, XO," the skipper said, shaking his head. "Once is happenstance, twice is coincidence, three times is enemy action."
>
> **"Yes, sir, nuke Mars now,"** Mbeki said, completing a joke so old its genesis had been lost. "But this is only twice."

Comment: Have you read *Von Neumann's War*?

Comment: I can't sort out any trace of it anymore; it's completely overwhelmed by memes about Musk's "let's nuke the poles to release water/gases" randomness, but I vaguely recall a joke - after the failures of Mars Observer, Mars Climate Orbiter and the Mars Polar Impactor - that we needed to get revenge on the Martians who were messing with our probes.  Not posting an answer 'cause I can't find any actual evidence, except the reference to it in *Von Neumann's War*.

Comment: *Von Neumann's War*, and references to it (including one where they refer to it as "a joke so old that we've forgotten the origins") in other John Ringo works looks about right. Next one I find that seems independent is 2013 *Born to Rock* by Gordon Korman where it's part of a Punk Rock lyric by a "King Maggot", commenting on American diplomacy.

Comment: If you wanna write up Von Neumann's War as an answer then I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vaguely remember this joke from 1999-2000 after the failure of the NASA *Mars Polar Lander* spacecraft (which was colloquially renamed the "Mars Polar Impactor").  *Mars Polar lander* was the 3rd failed Mars mission in a row: all 3 that were sent in the 1998 synod failed, JAXA's *Nozomi*, *Mars Climate Orbiter* and *Mars Polar Lander*.  With 3 failures from 3 successive missions, someone came up with the "3 times is enemy action" quote.

A description of the joke appears in Ringo's *Von Neumann's War*:

> "You know, when I came up with the idea for that 'Nuke Mars Now' bumpersticker when all those probes started disappearing, I meant it then, and I reiterate the sentiment now.  Once is happenstance, twice is coincidence, three times is enemy action:  NUKE MARS NOW!  I knew everybody should have listened to me!"

I don't specifically recall bumper stickers, or that precise wording, but someone did make a t-shirt with approximately that sentiment, that we needed to take revenge on the Martians for destroying our probes.  (I remember seeing it at Millennium Philcon, one of the few times I've managed to make it to Worldcon.)